# Bird identification- Crane

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

What species of crane is this?

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Today afternoon, I found this crane among a group of white cranes that were moving around a herd of buffaloes. I live in West Bengal, India if it matters.

Is it an eastern cattle egret,*[Bubulcus ibis coromandus](http://avibase.bsc-eoc.org/species.jsp?avibaseid=0653A8ADF672E188)* in breeding plumage?

Comment: Some of the photos appearing in the avibase page for Cattle egret look really similar, for instance https://www.flickr.com/photos/33816646@N06/5834155140.

Comment: It does. I found a page of Avibase about Bubulcus ibis coromandus with similar photographs.

Comment: Yes, It is for sure a cattle egret.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a cattle egret displaying its breeding plumage.

The [**cattle egret**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle_egret) (***Bubulcus ibis***) is a [**cosmopolitan**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmopolitan_distribution) species of heron (family Ardeidae) found in the tropics, subtropics and warm temperate zones.

Specifically, this is the eastern subspecies, ***B. ibis coromandus***.

[image: eastern cattle egret]

<sup>***B. ibis coromandus*** [source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bubulcus_ibis_coromandus.JPG)]</sup>

[image: Cattle egret -- http://pick4.pick.uga.edu/mp/20p?see=I_LHT5563&res=640]

<sup>***B. ibis ibis*** © Larry Thompson, 2007-2015</sup>

The cattle egret is the only member of the monotypic genus *Bubulcus*, although some authorities regard two of its subspecies as full species, the **western cattle egret** and the **eastern cattle egret**.

- The eastern subspecies ***B. ibis coromandus***, described by Pieter Boddaert in 1783, breeds in Asia and Australasia, and the western subspecies (***B. ibis ibis***) occupies the rest of the species range, including the Americas.
- The eastern subspecies (*B. ibis coromandus*) differs from the nominate subspecies in breeding plumage in that **the buff color on its head extends to the cheeks and throat, and the plumes are more golden in color**.

*B. ibis* usually feeds in seasonally inundated grasslands, pastures, farmlands, wetlands and rice paddies. Their name comes from their tendency to **often accompany cattle or other large mammals** in these areas, where they catch insects attracted to and small vertebrates disturbed by these animals.

Originally native to parts of Asia, Africa and Europe, *B. ibis* has undergone a rapid expansion in its distribution and successfully colonized much of the rest of the world in the last century.

[image: cattle egret range]

<sup>[Source: [Discover Life](http://pick4.pick.uga.edu/mp/20q?search=Bubulcus+ibis)]</sup>

Major Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle_egret)